# I'm trying to make a custom cell in table view but nothing showed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Like the title said, I'm trying to make a `UITableView` with custom cells, all the thing works properly, the array to make the cells it's okey and it contents the elements but when you show the application all the cells are void.
Here is the code of the `UIViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class GastosViewController: UIViewController {

    let idUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName
    var arrayGastos = [Gastos]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        var ref : DatabaseReference
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(idUser!).child("Gastos")
        ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            for j in value!{ 
                let i = j.value as? NSDictionary
                let titulo = i?["Nombre"] as? String
                let descripcion = i?["Descripcion"] as? String
                let precio = i?["precio"] as? Float
                let fecha = i?["Fecha"] as? String
                let gastoAux = Gastos(titulo: titulo!, descripcion: descripcion!, precio: precio!, date: fecha!)
                print(titulo, descripcion, fecha, precio)
                self.arrayGastos.append(gastoAux)
            }
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}

extension GastosViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayGastos.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let fila = arrayGastos[indexPath.row]
        let celda = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CeldaGastos") as! Celda

        celda.setCelda(celda: fila)
        return celda 
    }

}
```

I believe that's that code it's okey, but I'm not sure at all, in addition I will add the code of "**Gastos**" what is the object that I'm generating to add to the array of cells.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Gastos {

    var titulo : String
    var descripcion : String
    var precio : Float
    var date : String

    init(titulo : String, descripcion : String, precio : Float, date : String) {
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.descripcion = descripcion
        self.precio = precio
        self.date = date
    }

}
```

And finally that's my `TableViewCell`:

```
import UIKit

class Celda: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var Titulo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Fecha: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Precio: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Descripcion: UILabel!

    func setCelda(celda : Gastos){
        Titulo.text = celda.titulo
        Descripcion.text = celda.descripcion
        Fecha.text = celda.date
        Precio.text = String(celda.precio)
    }

}
```

I'm new to Swift programation, so maybe it's an stupid error, my view controller and my cell has a custom class for them in the storyboard but the table doesn't have it, it's a table into a view controller. Please I really need help thanks

Comment: It may be that you haven't registered the table view cell in your view did load yet

Answer (score 2):

You need to reload as the call to firebase is asynchronous

```
self.arrayGastos.append(gastoAux)
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Also think of whehter you need `ref.observe(.value)` or `ref.observeSingleEvent(of:.value)`

Answer (score 0):

Add following `didSet` block to your data source, so it refreshes the `UITableView` when `arrayGastos` changes

```
var arrayGastos = [Gastos]() {
    didSet {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And instead of `for-in` use following `Array.compactMap`

```
let array = value?.compactMap { j in
    guard let i = j.value as? [String : Any] else { return nil }

    let titulo = i["Nombre"] as? String
    let descripcion = i["Descripcion"] as? String
    let precio = i["precio"] as? Float
    let fecha = i["Fecha"] as? String
    print(titulo, descripcion, fecha, precio)

    return Gastos(titulo: titulo ?? "", descripcion: descripcion ?? "", precio: precio ?? 0, date: fecha ?? "")
}
self.arrayGastos = array ?? []
```

*Note* avoid force unwrapping optionals using `!`

Comment: isn't this inefficient because it will reload for every object append

Comment: Yeah I have implemented it and when you add a new thing, it reload all to the table again

Comment: `didSet` block will be called only **once**, at this line `self.arrayGastos = array ?? []`